# Creating a vector in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, p5.js

I seem to have problems with nesting a vector in an array. I have used createVector(), but found that that didn't work. I looked at other articles, though they applied to non p5 javascript, and this is where I currently am at:

```
function makePoints() {
    var cities = [];

    if (difficulty === 'hard') {
        cities.length = 40;

        for (i = 0; i < cities.length + 1; i++) {
            cities.push(new createVector(random(20, width - 20), random(20, height - 20)));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are first saying `cities.length = 40` which populates the array with 40 `undefined`. Then you are pushing on top of that but using the array that you are pushing to as the length to stop. So first push makes length 41, second push makes length 42. You are running into an infinite loop because `i` will never reach `cities.length + 1` (which should just be `cities.length`).

If you want to make your array 40 in length, then instead of pushing do this:

```
for (i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
    cities[i] = createVector(random(20, width - 20), random(20, height - 20));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you change `cities.length`? Wy not just:

```js
var difficulty = 'hard';
function setup() {
  createCanvas(720, 400);
  makePoints();
}


function makePoints() {
  var cities = [],
      citiesSize = 40;

  if (difficulty === 'hard') {
    for (i = 0; i < citiesSize; i++) {
      cities.push(createVector(random(20, width - 20), random(20, height - 20)));
    }
  }
  console.log(cities);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.14/p5.min.js"></script>
```